# Sum sub-matrices according to row index containing numerical data as strings

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How to sum each each columns of sub part of cell？
Given a cell A

```
A = {'a'  '546.8'  '543.5'  '544'  
  'a'  '641.9'  '637.4'  '632.3'
  'a'  '214.7'  '214.1'  '231.8'
  'a'  '256.9'  '255.6'  '254.2'
  'c'  '356'    '355.1'  '354.4'
  'c'  '759'    '759.6'  '756.2'
  'c'  '352.2'  '350.4'  '350.8'
  'f'  '234'    '230.3'  '232.3'
  'f'  '225'    '223.5'  '221.8'}
```

To separate A into sub cell according to different letter in the first column of A. And sum each columns of the the sub cell.

The anticipated result is:

```
B = {'a'  '1660.3'  '1650.6'  '1662.3'  
  'c'  '1467.2'    '1465.1'  '1461.4'
  'f'  '459'    '453.8'  '454.1'}
```

Comment: why do you want to keep the numbers as strings? Cell Arrays can contain mixed data types.

Comment: I keep it the same as it imported from excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no loop required:

```
%// get unique rows
[ids,~,subs] = unique(A(:,1))
%// transform string data to numeric data
vals = str2double(A(:,2:end))
%// sum unique rows
sums = accumarray(subs, 1:numel(subs), [], @(x) {sum(vals(x,:),1)} )
%// output result
out = [ids(:),num2cell(cell2mat(sums))]
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions is

```
[B,~,idxs]= unique(A(:,1))
for k=2:size(A,2)
    B(:,k)= num2cell(accumarray(idxs,str2double(A(:,k))))
end
```